# Jquery UI and Webpack, images are not loaded

Tags: jquery-ui, webpack

I'm using webpack to load jquery ui and everything except images works fine. This is because Webpack generates all images into a `dist/fonts` folder while the javascript/css is bundled into a `dist/js/vendor.js` file.

This causes a problem since the urls for backgrounds in the jquery ui css has the path `background-image: images/someImage.png`

So when jquery ui has been "webpackified", the paths for all `background-image` rules are broken.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide your webpack config. If you using `file-loader` for images be sure that `[path]` is passed to `name` option (`file?name=[path][name].[ext]`) https://github.com/webpack/file-loader#filename-template-placeholders